# Buttons in JPanel SOUTH moving next to elements in JPanel NORTH when window is widened

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, border-layout

I am writing some simple code that is supposed to have rows and is supposed to have a label and textinput on the top row and 4 buttons across the bottom row. When the window is resized, everything should stay where it is and not flow into the same row. Right now I'm missing something that stops my bottom row from moving to my top row when the jframe gets wider.

The structure is something like JFRAME(ContainerPanel NORTH(NORTH: subPanelTop(Label and Input), SOUTH: subPanelBottom(Buttons))

When I open the program and have the JFrame at 200px width, everything appears in two rows like it should, but when I resize it to be wider everything appears in the top row. How do I get these to stay as two rows on top of each other no matter what the width?

My homework says that I "must use borderlayout".

Code:

myEventA.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class myEventA extends JFrame{
    public myEventA(){
        JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
        JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel();
        this.setTitle("MyEventA");


        JPanel subPanelTop = new JPanel();
        JLabel currentValueLbl = new JLabel("Current Value: ",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        JTextField currentValue = new JTextField(15);
        subPanelTop.add(currentValueLbl);
        subPanelTop.add(currentValue);
        containerPanel.add(subPanelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        JPanel subPanelBottom = new JPanel();
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("+");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("-");
        JButton btn3 = new JButton("Reset");
        JButton btn4 = new JButton("Quit");
        subPanelBottom.add(btn1);
        subPanelBottom.add(btn2);
        subPanelBottom.add(btn3);
        subPanelBottom.add(btn4);
        containerPanel.add(subPanelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        containerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        this.add(containerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

TestMyEventA.java

```
import javax.swing.*;   // for JFrame, JPanel, JLabel, JTextField, 
import java.awt.*;      // for BorderLayout
public class TestMyEventA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        myEventA test = new myEventA();
        test.setSize(200,300);

        test.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        test.setVisible(true);
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: `My homework says that I "must use borderlayout".` - I think you don't understand the requirement. The content pane of the frame uses a BorderLayout. But then you add panels to the content pane and these panels can each use a different layout manager. So you can nest panels to get your desired layout. `but when I resize it to be wider everything appears in the top row` - this is because the default layout manager for a JPanel is the FlowLayout. Components are displayed on a single line, but will wrap when there is no space on the line.

Comment: So the solution is to use a different layout manager on the child panels you add to the content pane of the frame, maybe a GridBagLayout or nested panels with different layout managers. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for examples of using each layout manager.

Comment: @camickr ahhh. thanks! Yeah this is way harder than just coding something to run on the command line. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to manually set all of my JFrames and JPanels to use BorderLayout by adding some lines of .setLayout(new BorderLayout());

It works now!

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class myEventA extends JFrame{
    public myEventA(){
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel();
        containerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setTitle("MyEventA");


        JPanel subPanelTop = new JPanel();
        JLabel currentValueLbl = new JLabel("Current Value: ",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        JTextField currentValue = new JTextField(15);
        subPanelTop.add(currentValueLbl);
        subPanelTop.add(currentValue);
        containerPanel.add(subPanelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        JPanel subPanelBottom = new JPanel();
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("+");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("-");
        JButton btn3 = new JButton("Reset");
        JButton btn4 = new JButton("Quit");
        subPanelBottom.add(btn1);
        subPanelBottom.add(btn2);
        subPanelBottom.add(btn3);
        subPanelBottom.add(btn4);
        containerPanel.add(subPanelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.add(containerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I had to manually set all of my JFrames` - as I said in my comment, the default layout manager for the frame is the BorderLayout, so that is not necessary.The real problem is that there is no need for the container panel. You can just add the two child panels to the frame directly. The child panels will then be place in the North/South of the frame.

Comment: Whoops. I must have missed that part. The main thing I looked at was that the panels used Flowlayout as their default manager. I'm sorry, I'm a bit tired right now. Thanks again! Excited to move further in the assignment now that I'm passed this hurdle.

Comment: Your solution will work but you added an extra layer. You now have JFrame -> content pane -> container panel -> child panels.